# Randomizing data within certain parameters in Excel?

Tags: excel

I frequently find myself working with data that's confidential, but wanting to share data that looks *similar* to my data with someone external to my project. This could be getting a product demonstration, or getting help in a forum - basically any scenario where I want someone to show me how to do something with my data, but I can't show them the actual data.

What usually happens in this scenario is I take anywhere between a few minutes and an hour to manually change the data, which is obviously really inconvenient.
I don't necessarily want to fill it with truly random numbers - maybe the sheet is filled with currency values in the billions, or one figure needs to be much bigger than the other figure.

What would be ideal would be a formula to do something like, say, randomly add or subtract any number between 0 and 500 from every cell in the sheet. Does anyone know a way to do something like that?

Comment: `RANDBETWEEN(-500, 500)` does what it says on the tin, and you can add that to the value of another cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a whole range to change, you can use the paste special to add value. And combine it with the RANDBETWEEN(-500, 500)

Here a short overview of how to use Paste Special with operations:
https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/use-paste-special-to-perform-calculations-while-pasting-in-excel/

Answer (score 2):

This short macro should meet your needs:

```
Sub randumb()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(2, 1)
        With Application.WorksheetFunction
            r.Value = r.Value + .RandBetween(-500, 500)
        End With
    Next r
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

***NOTE:***

The macro only changes data cells, not formula cells.